# Magento 2.0.4 - minicart working on en_US, buggy on de_DE store language setting

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

We have the weird bug where the minicart is generating an exception in the console when having `de_DE` als language enabled, but it throws another error when `en_US` is enabled.

Working on `en_US`:

[image: Cart on en_US]
[image: Console on en_US]

Working on `de_DE`:

[image: Minicart on de_DE]
[image: Console on de_DE]

We are currently using Magento 2.0.4 and upgrading on this Env is not an option due to the bugs on higher Magento2-Versions.

The question now is: how can we get rid of those two errors? Our desired language is `de_DE`, so getting it working on `de_DE` would already be a great success.